# actionscript dynamic text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dynamic-text

I have a text box set up in my project and it works fine when I test it but when I put it in the web page it only shows part of the text

here is the setup [image]

and when I build it I get this [image] but then when I put it in the web i get this [image]

i've tried using both embedding and using device font without success anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong ?

**EDIT**
here are the only calls to text box in acitonscript

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void{
    try{
        //try to stuff
    } catch(error:TypeError) {
        error_txt.text = error.toString();
    }
}

    function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {

        error_txt.text = e.text;    
    }
```

Comment: I suspect it is working fine & that adobe player might be preventing the full error to be generated as per it's settings in the client side.

Comment: how would the player settings affect the text box behavior

Comment: I think he means that you don't get the full length of the message's text. To check that you can test with your own text, and do not rely on the error generated.

Comment: that seems to be it I can put my own text in it works fine so its like only half the error is showing  is there a way to make the full error show

Comment: then you should try testing with different player versions

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you are using for setting the text? Since in the actual page 'Error #2124' is centered over the loading symbol, it looks to me like either that is the only text that actually ends up in error_txt OR the dynamic text's width and height are being changed so that 'Error #2124' is all that fits.

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess, set the line behavior type to multiline

Comment: I thought that was in the screen shot but I guess not it is set to multiline thank you though